# jQuery adding background color on link when hover, background stay while mouse hovers sub-menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am trying to add a background color to the main link , which shows a sub menu. for now only sub menu is displayed, as soon as mouse leaves the main link, the color goes back to original background color.

```
    <nav>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="index.php">home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="intro.php">intro</a>
            </li>
            <li id="services"><a href="#">services</a>
                <ul id="subMenu">
                    <li><span>one</span></li>
                    <li><span>two</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">contacts</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<style>
#services {background:yellow;}
#subMenu {position:absolute;display:none;width:250px;}
#subMenu li {border:none;display:list-item!important;width:100%;background:#e13b30;}
#subMenu li span {color:#fff!important;line-height:50px;}
.bgRed {background-color:#e13b30;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#nav #services').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('#services', this).stop().addClass('bgRed'),
            $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(10);
        }
    );

});
</script>
```

Comment: I think we need more of the HTML as it looks weird in this Fiddle demo, http://jsfiddle.net/E6YBP/ - what exactly is your question? What do you want it to do?

Comment: I need the yellow background to become red when mouse hovers that link, and it should stay red when hovering sub links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this

```
$('#nav #services').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $(this).find("a").toggleClass('bgRed').stop();
            $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $(this).find("a").toggleClass('bgRed').stop();
            $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(10);
        }
    );
```

Also you have an error on your class definition

```
.bgRed{background-color,#e13b30;}
```

Should be

`.bgRed{background-color:#e13b30;}` Notice the `:`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRHQ9/)

Comment: Yw, i hope that's what your trying to do

Answer (score 1):

add the following to your script

```
 $('#submenu').hover(
    function () {
        //highlight parent
        $(this).parent().addClass('bgRed');
    }, 
    function () {
        //un - highlight parent
        $(this).parent().removeClass('bgRed');
    }
);
```

**update: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/BbzED/)**
well after your weird update of removing `removeClass` from the question, i checked the code in a fiddle,

in the below code

```
 $('#services', this).stop().addClass('bgRed')
```

you are passing `this` as the context. so JQuery will search for element with id `services` inside `this`, which refers to the `#services` element itself. hence it won't work.

also `stop()` seems to be unnecessary..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this from CSS also and there is no need of script.. Please check this [**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/4j9Vb/)